# Using MaxDegreeOfParallelism versus partitioning data before using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I have a processing task where I have to analyze lots of data in the fastest way possible. I am wondering if there is any benefits/drawback of using one way over the other...

I have a quad core processor with hyperthreading (so logical 8 cores). We will use that for the example:

[**Option 1**] Use `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`

```
int numCores = 8;
Parallel.ForEach(items, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = numCores  }, item =>
{
    //// Process item
});
```

[**Option 2**] Paritioning the data into map:

```
int numCores = 8;
for (int i = 0; i < numCores ; i++)
{
    threadMap.Add(i, new List<Item>());
}

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    threadMap[i % numCores].Add(items[i]);
}

Parallel.ForEach(threadMap.Keys, thread =>
{
    foreach(var item in threadMap[thread])
    {
        //// Process item
    }
});
```

Right now, my code uses option 1. Is there any reason why I should switch to option 2? It seems that option 2 could have issues if the data is partitioned unevenly (processing time wise).

Is there an option 3?

Comment: Can't you execute and profile both?

Comment: In execution time, they seem to be the same (i might not have the right data to test this properly). Is there ever a scenario where option 2 would be favorable?